# Is a module over a (c-)soft sheaf (c-)soft?

Tags: sheaf-theory, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

In the context of Riemann Surfaces, or $\mathbb C$ manifolds (or even more generally) I wonder if a module over a c-soft sheaf $\mathcal S$ is itself c-soft which I believe implies soft if the space is Hausdorff. I tried to to show it  but I'm not sure how to use the softness of $\mathcal S$.

So take $\mathcal F$ a $\mathcal S$-module and $K\subseteq X$ compact. Consider $i\colon K\hookrightarrow X$ the inclusion and $s\in \Gamma(K,i^{-1}\mathcal F)$ a global section of $i_*i^{-1}\mathcal F$. Now we have that $\Gamma(K,i^{-1}\mathcal F)=\operatorname{colim}_{U\supseteq K}\Gamma(U,\mathcal F)$ so $s$ is represented by some $t\in\Gamma(U,\mathcal F)$ which is a $\Gamma(U,\mathcal S)$-module. At this point how can we use our softness assumption of $\mathcal S$ ?

Comment: For people coming by, I have no written proof but the idea is to use some kind of bump function. The case where $\mathcal S=C^{\infty}$ on say a manifold can be used by considering $K\subseteq U_1\subseteq \overline{U_1}\subseteq U_2\subseteq \overline{U_2}\subseteq U$ and having a bump function $f$ which is $1$ on $K$ and 0 on $U\backslash U_2$ so we can glue $fs$ with the zero section. In this case the existence of $f$ is guaranteed by say Prop 2.25 of Introduction to smooth manifolds (Lee) in the real case. I believe the general case uses the same idea.